# Immutable data in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, variables, angular, typescript, immutability

PLOT:

I have a protected variable named `myVar` and it is structure and data is defined by the constructor such as

```
this.myVar = this.legacy ? this.legacy.listing : this.default;
```

When you edit `myVar` it also change `this.default` structure and data. So my problem is simple : how would you keep `this.default` immutable ?

Any help appreciated,

PS: functions such as

```
private default = (): Structure[] => {
  return [{
    param1: 'param1'
  }]
}
```

is not what I aim.

Comment: Store it as a `string` maybe

Comment: If you want to keep this.default immutable and also prevent myVar to mutate its inner properties, then you can use deep-freeze, please refer to my answer below. However, if you need to protect this.default, but allow myVar to mutate independently, `default = (): Structure[] => { return ...; }` in your PS section is the only answer.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: You need to make `myVar` and your default structure be different objects. `readonly` is not the solution.**

#### `readonly` is Not the Solution

`readonly` is not helpful for what you are trying to do. If you use `readonly` on a primitive type like `number` or `string`, the field is effectively immutable. However, a field that holds an `Object` (and its derivatives like `Function` and `Array`) contains a *reference* to the object. **`readonly` makes the reference immutable, not the object itself**. This is exactly the same as `const`. Here's an example with const:

```
class Structure {
    public prop: number = 1;
}

const a: Structure = new Structure();
console.log(a.prop);
a.prop++; // It does not matter that `a` was marked `const`.
console.log(a.prop);
```

The code above will show:

```
1
2
```

We've been able to mutate `a` even though it is readonly.

Now, here's an example with `readonly`:

```
class Structure {
    public prop: number = 1;
}

class Something {
    // This is the analogue to `default` in your question. I don't like
    // the name default because it is a keyword and looks funky here in 
    // syntax highlighting.
    private static readonly defaultStructure = new Structure();

    readonly myVar: Structure;

    constructor() {
        this.myVar = Something.defaultStructure;
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.myVar.prop++;
    }

    // `readonly defaultStructure` prevents this:
    // evil() {
    //     Something.defaultStructure = new Structure();
    // }
}

const something = new Something();
console.log(something.myVar);
something.doSomething();
const somethingElse = new Something();
console.log(somethingElse.myVar);
```

This shows:

```
Structure { prop: 1 }
Structure { prop: 2 }
```

We've made both `myVar` and `defaultStructure` readonly, but modifying `myVar` modifies `defaultStructure`

Objection: "But, Louis, you big goof, you should make `prop` readonly!"

No, if I make `prop` `readonly` then I cannot modify `myVar` anymore, *but I want to be able to modify `myVar`!*

#### Ok, what now?

Ultimately, there's no amount of tapdancing with `readonly` or decorators or `Object.freeze` that will give you want you want. As long as both `myVar` and `defaultStructure` are referring to the same object, you'll either a) mutate `defaultStructure` through `myVar`, or b) if you make the object pointed to by `defaultStructure` immutable you'll also make the object pointed to by `myVar` immutable because *they are the same object*. **You need to make it so that `myVar` and your default structure are different objects.**

You have a few options for this:

1. You can **construct `myVar` anew** instead of assigning from a default value. You've shown an example of this in your question and said you were not aiming or that, but it is one valid option.
2. You could **assign to `myVar` a clone** of your default structure. There are many ways to clone objects. In the general case, a deep copy is needed. There are many libraries out there for deep copying. You should research what would work best for your specific case.

In this case, of the two, I would prefer option 1 because I know what the default structure must contain. I use cloning for when I must obtain a copy of a structure that can have a number of different values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [readonly](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html) keyword.

It enables you to assign a value once, after that, changing the value of variable is not permitted.

Comment: This feature came with TypeScript 2.0, which got released 7 days ago - so one should update their TS version before trying that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've heard about readonly in TS but is it an ECMAScript standard ? ES 6 ?

Comment: There is a [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword in ES6, but I'm not 100% sure it will behave just like `readonly` in TypeScript (I don't know if it will allow the use of ternary operator for assignment, which is the case in your code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deep-freeze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-freeze) to freeze your default object. Make sure you use it with `"use strict";`, the browsers will enforce immutability at runtime, i.e., they will throw exception when trying to modify any properties in the default object. E.g.,

```js
"use strict";

this.default = ...;
deepFreeze(this.default);

this.myVar = this.legacy ? this.legacy.listing : this.default;

// Browsers will throw exception on following statement.
this.myVar[0].param1 = "modified";
```

Comment: The OP clearly wants to be able to mutate `this.myVar`.

Comment: Then, what is wrong with `default = (): Structure[] => {  return ...; }` in his PS section? That is the only possible solution.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I explained in my answer. It is not rare that people come to SO asking for another way to do something, not realizing that the way they already do it is really what *they should do*.